# When using Facebook app to share, the confirm to share button disappear(but works in Safari)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, facebook-social-plugins, facebook-sharer

I put a Facebook share button with below code (using Rails):

```
<div class="social_share_column">
<%= link_to image_tag("facebook_share.png", alt: "login", size: "93x32"),
    'https://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?
    app_id=' + ENV['FACEBOOK_KEY'] +
    '&display=page&
    &link=http://www.ad-judge.com/posts/'+ post.slug +
    '&picture=http://img.youtube.com/vi/'+ post.youtube_video_id +
    '/hqdefault.jpg&name='+ post.title +
    '&redirect_uri='+ request.original_url,
    :target => :blank %> 
</div>
```

if I use Safari, the share function works well

http://bit.ly/1ihe91e

But if I use Facebook app to share, the button at top right disappear

http://bit.ly/1jEHVhG

Can anyone help?

By the way, this share button also works on desktop.

Thank you.

update:

From facebook developer bug report, they suggest me use share button directly.

But the icon is just too small on mobile, so I think using facebook javascript is the only solution for this mobile only issue.

Comment: This is where Ithe link comes from:  https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/feed-dialog

Comment: Bug report to Facebook: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/287566641410625/